# how to update docker images and restart it for ReactJS app

Tags: reactjs, docker, go, nginx

I have a reactjs app, and now I dockerized it with the following `Dockerfile`

```
# get the base node image
FROM node:alpine as builder

# set the working dir for container
WORKDIR /frontend

# copy the json file first
COPY ./package.json /frontend

# install npm dependencies
RUN yarn install
ENV REACT_APP_API_ADDRESS=http://localhost:7001

# copy other project files
COPY . .

# build the folder
RUN yarn build

# Handle Nginx
FROM nginx
COPY --from=builder /frontend/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./docker/nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

and my `nginx` conf is simple like below:

```
server {
  listen 7001;
  server_name _;

  index index.html;
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;

  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

  location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html =404;
  }
}
```

and then, I build it and push it to docker hub, I hope if I have publish a new image or you can said the latest one, the `reactjs` application should popup a window or a notification to let the `user` click it (I can make it so far).

and then, if user click the `update notification button`, the another server i call it `hook_upgrade_server` in anther container, which will get a signal and then it will execute `docker pull reactjs` and restart it by `docker run -d -p7001:7001 reactjs` docker container with latest images.

Which mean, I want to install two container on the user `host`:

- `reactjs` do some business
- `hook_upgrade_server` for wait user `click` signal and `pull latest image` and `restart`

So, How can i make it happen?

Comment: You should use docker-sompose for that purpose.

Comment: This sounds like you're looking for a _continuous deployment_ system that can update your system whenever you commit to your source-control repository.  I probably wouldn't ask an end user to initiate that step, and I'd be very careful about making an API accessible that directly interfaced with Docker (security mistakes there can compromise the entire host).

Comment: @DavidMaze yes! that's what I want. I just want to deploy the client side on the customer host. and want to upgrade it remote in the feature if we have latest version  .